# Neighbouring UILabel won't wrap text

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem with UILabels that are created in a loop.

When left label has too long text, it pushes the right label out of view, it doesn't wrap its content to the next line.

I have tried setting up different heights, constraints and hugging/compression values with no effect whatsoever.

This is part of my code that causes problems:

```
for (key_name, display_name) in ConfiguratorMaps.cableMap {

        if(searchResultsObject?.fuse!.row!.value(named: key_name) == nil) {
            continue;
        }

        let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(8, 8, 20, 80))
        //titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
        titleLabel.text = display_name
        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        //titleLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(<#T##priority: UILayoutPriority##UILayoutPriority#>, forAxis: <#T##UILayoutConstraintAxis#>)

        let xconstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: titleLabel, //-- the object that we want to constrain
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, //-- the attribute of the object we want to constrain
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, //-- how we want to relate THIS object to A DIFF object
            toItem: contentView, //-- this is the different object we want to constrain to
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, //-- the attribute of the different object
            multiplier: 1, //-- multiplier
            constant: 8 //-- (Take a look here, its a minus)
        )

        let yconstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: titleLabel, //-- the object that we want to constrain
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, //-- the attribute of the object we want to constrain
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, //-- how we want to relate THIS object to A DIFF object
            toItem: lastLabel, //-- this is the different object we want to constrain to
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, //-- the attribute of the different object
            multiplier: 1, //-- multiplier
            constant: 30 //+ i * 35 //-- (Take a look here, its a minus)
        )

        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let valueLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(8, 8, 50, 21))
        //valueLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        //titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right

        if(searchResults?.resultType == .Fuse) {
            valueLabel.text = searchResultsObject?.fuse!.row!.value(named: key_name)
        } else {
            valueLabel.text = searchResultsObject?.circutBreaker!.row!.value(named: key_name)
        }

        valueLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)
        valueLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        valueLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(700, forAxis: UILayoutConstraintAxis.Horizontal)

        let xValueconstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: valueLabel, //-- the object that we want to constrain
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, //-- the attribute of the object we want to constrain
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, //-- how we want to relate THIS object to A DIFF object
            toItem: contentView, //-- this is the different object we want to constrain to
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, //-- the attribute of the different object
            multiplier: 1, //-- multiplier
            constant: -22 //-- (Take a look here, its a minus)
        )

        let yValueconstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: valueLabel, //-- the object that we want to constrain
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, //-- the attribute of the object we want to constrain
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, //-- how we want to relate THIS object to A DIFF object
            toItem: lastValueLabel, //-- this is the different object we want to constrain to
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, //-- the attribute of the different object
            multiplier: 1, //-- multiplier
            constant: 30 //+ i * 35 //-- (Take a look here, its a minus)
        )

        let interValueConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: titleLabel, //-- the object that we want to constrain
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, //-- the attribute of the object we want to constrain
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.LessThanOrEqual, //-- how we want to relate THIS object to A DIFF object
            toItem: valueLabel, //-- this is the different object we want to constrain to
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, //-- the attribute of the different object
            multiplier: 1, //-- multiplier
            constant: 8 //+ i * 35 //-- (Take a look here, its a minus)
        )

        valueLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        constraints.append(xconstraint)
        constraints.append(yconstraint)
        constraints.append(xValueconstraint)
        constraints.append(yValueconstraint)
        constraints.append(interValueConstraint)

        contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(valueLabel)

        lastValueLabel = valueLabel
        lastLabel = titleLabel
    }
```

The result looks like this:
[image: overlapping ui labels]

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: What happens if you set up a forced width on the label you have on the left? Also do you see any conflicts in the system log?

Answer (score 0):

The way I can see it, You have 2 options:

1. Use 1 UILabel, and set I'ts number of lines to 0, so it will know to grew if needed. And create a contraint to right side of the screen (the same as you did with leading, add one trailing). And each loop, **add text to the label**, insted of adding one more label.

Something like this:

```
let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(8, 8, 20, 80))
titleLabel.text = display_name
titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(titleLabel)

let leadingConstaint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

let trailingConstaint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

let topConstaint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

self.view.addConstraints([leadingConstaint, trailingConstaint, topConstaint])


for (key_name, display_name) in ConfiguratorMaps.cableMap {

    if(searchResultsObject?.fuse!.row!.value(named: key_name) == nil) {
        continue;
    }
        titleLabel.text += display_name

}
```

2. You can calculate the size of the screen, and then move the last label down a row when reaching the edge of the screen. But then you are not using the power of AutoLayout, so I less recommend this option.

Answer (score 0):

set TitleLabel ContentHuggingPriority to 250
set ValueLabel ContentHuggingPriority to 251
set ValueLabel horizontal Content Compression resistance priority to 751.

By setting these values it will show full text for value label.